# Change background color row on Oracle APEX interactive grid using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have an interactive grid with one of the column id's set to `DaysIn` and I have set the static ID to `di`.

I would like to change the background row color based on the the value of the number in `DaysIn`.

I have added the following code to a dynamic action on after refresh - but it's not working.

```js
$('td[headers="di"]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() < '30') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({
      "background-color": "beige"
    });
  }

  if ($(this).text() >= '30' && $(this).text() < '60') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({
      "background-color": "lightgreen"
    });
  }

  if ($(this).text() >= '60' && $(this).text() < '65') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({
      "background-color": "lightblue"
    });
  }

  if ($(this).text() >= '65') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({
      "background-color": "pink"
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1pcfmxq7/. I would suggest you check the console for errors, and also ensure that jQuery is loaded in the page and that you're executing the logic above *after* the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Also, as an aside you can improve the code quality by using an array of objects to contain the max values/colors lookup which will help to DRY the logic, and also by using `parseFloat()` (or `parseInt()`) to ensure you're doing a comparison on an explicit numerical values instead of relying on type coercion: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ux3es17q/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried your code which I like more that my first stab. But it still doesn't work and I tried both parseInt() and parseFloat(). And I have my DA set to after refresh.

Answer (score -1):

I know you specified you want to use JavaScript. But, if you already use Oracle Apex, consider using built-in capabilities and *highlight* rows using Interactive Grid's "Actions":

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did. But I want to lock other users to mess with that, so I thought that hard coded would be better.

Comment: They can mess with that only temporarily because it is you (developer) who **saved** report definition. So, even if they do modify something, it'll be reverted when they return to the same grid.

Comment: I didn't know that?  I'll apply the built in highlight again and do some more testing to see if it will fit my use case.

Comment: End users can save their own report layouts (that works ... huh, *for ages*), but - as I said - default report definition is yours (developer's) only. Initially, your version of report is being displayed. They can choose to display any of report layouts they saved, if they want.